# Best way to handle properties that may not exist until later point

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am working on an application and in one of my static classes, I have some properties that will be filepaths of some roaming directories.

There is a chance that the appdata directory has been cleared, thus the roaming directories are gone, so I will get an error:

```
System.Initialization.TypeException
```

Since the directories do not exist.  I have methods in the class that will recreate the appdata directory once it is found that they are non-existent.  The only problem is I don't know how to bypass the System.Initialization.TypeException originally, then use the methods I wrote to create the specified directories and update the properties with the new values.  I've been going in circles and am not getting anywere.  Currently, the properties are declared as follows:

```
private static string appRoaming { get; } = $@"{EnvironManager.appData}\App Specific";
private static string sysPattern { get; } = "sys*";
private static string appSysDir { get; } = FileSystem.GetSubdirFromPattern(appRoaming, sysPattern);
```

Essentially, the appSysDir will not work because the FileSystem.GetSubdirFromPattern will not find the appRoaming directory.

Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `{ get; } =` use ` => ` so the (static) property is not initialized on (type) construction, but only evaluates on access. Or do ` => _appSysDir ?? (_appSysDir = …);` to initialize the backing field at first property access and for subsequent accesses reuse the cached value.

Comment: Can't you expand the getter and write something like `get { if (!Directory.Exists([TheAppPathThatShouldBeThere])) { Directory.CreateDirectory([TheAppPathThatShouldBeThere]); } return [TheAppPathThatShouldBeThere];`? Can you use `Application.UserAppDataPath`?

Comment: @ckuri thank you very much.  I think I will go with that.  It sounds that if I use it that way it will be more CPU-intensive rather than memory-intensive which will be much better.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the suggestion.  I am actually not creating any appdata for this application, rather modifying appdata for third party applications.  I think I will end up using expression bodied members as suggested by ckuri.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [expression-bodied-members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Example:

```
public class Location
{
   private string locationName;

   public Location(string name)
   {
      locationName = name;
   }

   public string Name => locationName;
}
```

In your case:

```
private static string GetAppSysDir() {
    try {
        return FileSystem.GetSubdirFromPattern(appRoaming, sysPattern);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle your exception
        // return some kind of string
    }
}
private static string appSysDir { get; } => GetAppSysDir;
```

Comment: Your last line wouldn’t compile as you can’t mix { get; } with => (which is already an implicit get) and you forget the brackets on the method.

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras thank you very much!  I will use that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetAppSysDir()` suggested from @Athanasios Kataras will do the work nicely, and will be called on every `get` invocation.

If you want the appSysDir be initialized only once, you can call the same method on initialization like

```
private static string appSysDir { get; } = GetAppSysDir(appRoaming, sysPattern);
```

This will work and not lead to a `TypeException`, because the originating `DirectoryNotFoundException` will be handled in the `catch` block.

Personally, I prefer to not do lengthy or complex work running on type initialization. It is depending on the situation, what is too lengthy or too complex.

You can add to the `get => delegate` solution proposed by @Athanasios some initialization handling like

```
if (!isAppSysDirInitialized) 
{
   // Do appSysDir initialization here.

   // After initialization:
   isAppSysDirInitialized = true;
} 
else
{
   return appSysDir;
}
```

This way combining both, not doing much work within the Type initilializer, and single init.